# Ionic 3 - how to change navBar background in the ts file

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, navbar

i have navbar component, and i want to change background color using color value from REST in the typeScript file. But i don't know ho to make it.

anythink sugestion ??

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like this with JS:

```
let element: any = document.getElementsByClassName(toolbar-background);
element[0].style.background = "#fff";
```

Answer (score 1):

In your template you can use binding like this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar [style.color]="myNavbarColor">
        <ion-title>Example</ion-title>
     </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Then in ts you can assign color in hex format:

```
myNavbarColor: string = “#FFFFFF
```

Now once you get color value from you API you can assign it via the bound variable:

```
// inside your api call response:
this.myNavbarColor = //here you put your color hex value.
```

Comment: Your pattern is good. But he asked about `background-color`. Maybe you just miss it.

Comment: Actually, I tested your code but it does not work because `<ion-navbar>` is parent element whcih has other child components. For most other simple elements, your code works.

Comment: Hey, indeed my goal was to show the pattern rather than exact solution;) i hope the author can adapt it

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Renderer2`. It's more safe and flexible on multi-platforms.

In this [article](https://medium.com/@kmathy/angular-manipulate-properly-the-dom-with-renderer-16a756508cba) which explain whe direct DOM access is not good,

> Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed. Permitting direct access to the DOM can make your application more vulnerable to XSS attacks. Carefully review any use of ElementRef in your code. Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead. Alternatively you take a look at Rendererwhich provides API that can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not supported.

**Usage**

```
import {Component, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Component(//skip)
class Page{
  constructor(public renderer: Renderer2) {}
  changeBackgroundColor(){
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('toolbar-background')[0],'background-color',"blue")
  }
}
```